# trigger jquery event when page loads

Tags: jquery

Hi all im using the following code either or really

```
<script type="text/javascript">$('#matTypeMst').val('2').trigger('change'); </script>

<script type="text/javascript">$('#matTypeMst').trigger('change'); </script>
```

to try and first pre select a value in a select box and then trigger the onchange event connected to it, but for some reason its not fireing can anyone help

thanks

Comment: 5 answers in one minute. Not bad. :) Besides the answers given, you can also place the script tag at the end of the `<body>`-element if applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:-

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#matTypeMst').val('2').trigger('change'); 

    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... });
$(function() { ... });
```

These guys are both triggered when the DOM is loaded. The second method is only a shorthand, they are identical.

```
$(window).load(function() { ... });
```

Is triggered when the document and all it's resources (scripts, styles, images, etc.) is loaded.

### Vanilla JS

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() { ... }, false);
```

Is the same as jQuery's `$(window).load()`, but without the jQuery.

### HTML

You can also use the DOM to run events. You won't need jQuery for that.

```
<body onload="initialize();">
```

The body's `onload` will fire when the body is loaded.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">initialize();</script>
</body>
```

By running a script at the end of your body, you can make sure your DOM is loaded.

Comment: +1 for showing all possibilities and for our good old friend VanillaJS.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in ready function

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#matTypeMst').val('2').trigger('change'); 

    });

 </script>
```

[Learn more about ready here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 0):

The DOM is probably not loaded when the script runs.  Wrap it in a `document.ready` handler like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#matTypeMst').val('2').trigger('change');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use

```
$(document).ready(function(){...});
```

[**Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)